# What is the best practice to keep frequently usable common functions in node.js/express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating web app using node.js and express.js. I want to keep functions, need frequently in separate file/module. What is the best way/practice to organize/create frequently usable functions among several script files/routes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use something like `lib/utils.js`.

Comment: @robertklep good point. thanks